# Where to upload data in Webgl -globe?

Tags: javascript, html

I've just downloaded the whole folder from this link:

https://github.com/dataarts/webgl-globe

I would like to do the same data visualization, but if I open the file  [`index.html`](https://github.com/dataarts/webgl-globe/blob/master/globe/index.html), inside the [`globe`](https://github.com/dataarts/webgl-globe/blob/master/globe/) directory, but the globe doesn't appear, and I don't know the problem.

Another doubt is: if I substitute the json file with my data (always in json format) it should work?

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: What error message do you get in the console? From my memory, I think you need to run a server that serves up that index.html, but let me double check that

Comment: if i click on the file the brower (Chrome) will open and show me this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v1JpafTt1CMxHUl7_dmplgK8sIZwUgXi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: don't know but if you want to make your own WebGL Globe there's [this](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-optimize-lots-of-objects.html) followed by [this](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-optimize-lots-of-objects-animated.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I see what your problem is- you'll need this content to be served up by a simple server of your choice. (The simplest of which is probably this Node.js package: [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) - you'll need [git](https://git-scm.com/) and [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed)

I've just got your demo working for you, with the following steps:

> 1. Get a simple node server. `npm install http-server -g` (you need it global installed)
> 2. Get the demo files: `git clone https://github.com/dataarts/webgl-globe.git` and `cd webgl-globe`.
> 3. Start the web server, from the current directory just run `http-server .`
> 4. Then in your browser navigate to http://localhost:8080/globe - and boom  it'll be working perfectly.

---

And in answer to your second question, as long as your data is in the following format, (the same as [this example data](https://github.com/dataarts/webgl-globe/blob/master/globe/population909500.json)) it should work fine when you plug your json in:

```
var data = [
    [
    'seriesA', [ latitude, longitude, magnitude, latitude, longitude, magnitude, ... ]
    ],
    [
    'seriesB', [ latitude, longitude, magnitude, latitude, longitude, magnitude, ... ]
    ]
];
```

---

I hope that helps, you'll have a lot of fun with WebGL, the globe is especially cool.

Source: I made [this demo](https://sentiment-sweep.com/globe), showing the sentiment of real-time Twitter data with a WebGL-based globe a while back.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
If i would re open the same file from another computer what should I do?
Should I host the globe on internet?

Comment: Yeah, your best option would be to host it on a server if you need it to be publicly available. Check out [Netlify](https://app.netlify.com/) or [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com) if your looking for something quick and free.

Comment: It will still work fine, whatever computer you're on. Just saying, server is always more fun ;)

Comment: I have downloaded the file of [this website](https://newnaw.com/pub/js/webglglobe/worldelevation), but my numbers are bigger (my max magnitude are maximum 100 millions), and the result is not good, because in the ploy I have a lot of black bars (too high numbers.) How can I solve this?
I don't know how to adjust the scale. Thanks for your help

Comment: But either way, in answer to that question, all you need to do is write a formater, that normalizes all your data before it gets plotted to the globe.